# os.path.exists is not working as expected in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to create a directory in the home path and re-check if the directory exists in the home path before re-creating using os.path.exists(), but its not working as expected.

```
if os.access("./", os.W_OK) is not True:
    print("Folder not writable")
    dir_name_tmp = subprocess.Popen('pwd', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    dir_name_tmp = dir_name_tmp.stdout.read()
    dir_name = dir_name_tmp.split('/')[-1]
    dir_name = dir_name.rstrip()

    os.system('ls ~/')
    print "%s"%dir_name

    if not os.path.exists("~/%s"%(dir_name)):
        print "Going to create a new folder %s in home path\n"%(dir_name)
        os.system('mkdir ~/%s'%(dir_name))
    else:
        print "Folder %s Already Exists\n"%(dir_name)
        os.system('rm -rf ~/%s & mkdir ~/%s'%(dir_name, dir_name))
else :
    print("Folder writable")
```

Output for the first time:

```
Folder not writable
Desktop  Downloads  Perforce  bkp  doc  project
hello.list
Going to create a new folder hello.list in home path
```

Output for the 2nd time:

```
Folder not writable
Desktop  Downloads  Perforce  bkp  doc  hello.list  project
hello.list
Going to create a new folder hello.list in home path

mkdir: cannot create directory `/home/desperado/hello.list': File exists
```

Its not going into the else loop though the directory is existing. Am I missing something ? Share in you inputs !

Updated Working Code With Suggestions Provided: Using $HOME directory and os.path.expandusr

```
if os.access("./", os.W_OK) is not True:
    log.debug("Folder Is Not writable")
    dir_name_tmp = subprocess.Popen('pwd', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    dir_name_tmp = dir_name_tmp.stdout.read()
    dir_name = dir_name_tmp.split('/')[-1]
    dir_name = dir_name.rstrip()

    log.debug("dir_name is %s"%dir_name)

    dir_name_path = (os.path.expanduser('~/%s'%(dir_name))).rstrip()
    log.debug("dir_name_path is %s"%(dir_name_path))

    # if not os.path.exists('~/%s'%(dir_name)):
    if not os.path.exists('%s'%(dir_name_path)):
        log.debug("Going to create a new folder %s in home path\n"%(dir_name))
        os.system('mkdir $HOME/%s'%(dir_name))
    else:
        log.debug("Folder %s Already Exists\n"%(dir_name))
        os.system('rm -rf %s'%(dir_name_path))
        os.system('mkdir $HOME/%s'%(dir_name))
else :
    log.debug("Folder Is Writable")
```

Comment: Don't use `x is not True` for comparisons. Just use `not x`.

Comment: You are just passing the `dir_name` and not the absolute path while checking in `os.path.exists()`. hence it is returning `False`.
Try passing absolute path of directory while calling `os.path.exists()`, it should work.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: Sorry I am not getting it. The issue is in the 2nd if condition i.e. if not os.path.exists("~/%s"%(dir_name)):. I am using if not case only.

Comment: @Tanu: I am indeed passing the absolute path. If you see I am using ~/%s i.e. ~/(Directory Name). I am looking for directory name in the home path, but still it says the directory is not there.

Comment: Python does not expand `~` automatically. Use `os.path.expanduser()`.

Comment: @Desperado: You are passing only `dir_name` which is initialized as `hello.list` as far as your output says. Also, what @Klaus D. is saying is correct.

Comment: Thanks @KlausD.for the suggestions. Got it working.

Comment: Thanks @Tanu for the clarifications.

Answer (score 6):

The tilde symbol `~` representing the home directory is a shell convention. It is expanded by the shell in `os.system`, but it is understood literally in Python.

So you create `<HOME>/<DIR>`, but test for `~/<DIR>`.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by [VPfB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5378816/vpfb), the tilde symbol is understood literally by Python. To fix this, you need to get your actual home directory.

Now, on different platforms, there are different paths for the home directory.

To get the home directory, [`os.path.expanduser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser) will be useful.

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.expanduser("~")
'/Users/ashish'
```